# Laravel Develoyment on AWS EC2

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, amazon-ec2, hosting

I am trying to deploy laravel 5.1 project on AWS EC2 cloud server and having an issue with laravel web site route URLs.

I ran the following commands to configure the EC2 ubuntu 14.04 LTS server.

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install mysql-server php5-mysql
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt
sudo apt-get install php5 php-pear
sudo apt-get install curl php5-curl php5-cli git
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```

getting the following error when I try access any route URLs but my home page is loading correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /register was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at xxxx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com Port 80
</address>
</body></html>
```

I have changed the apache route URL to the public folder of my laravel project without any success. Also I tried to enable the following virtual host file but still got the same error.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mynewhost.com 
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mynewhost/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 
</VirtualHost>
```

I ran the following command to grant permission to the storage folder

```
 chmod -R 777 storage
```

do I need to grant any permission to my laravel project folder?

appreciate any help.

Comment: have you enabled the rewrite module? try sudo a2enmod rewrite and restart your apache

Comment: @JLPuro yes i did. i will update my question.

Comment: it loads the /var/www/html/mynewhost/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php template as the home page. So I think Route::get('/', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin') route is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my configuration for Laravel 5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04

You might need to enable your rewrite engine

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

If that doesn't work you can change the virtualhost configuration to something like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName laravel.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mynewhost/public

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/html/mynewhost/>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Additionally add the ServerName to `/etc/hosts`

```
<your-server-ip-address> laravel.example.com
```

Comment: here you have changed the ubuntu server web root directory to laravel website's public folder. how do you host 2 laravel web sites on this same server with this configuration?

Comment: You could try setting the `DocumentRoot` to `/var/www/html/` I think it should still work.